# android: showing a progress dialog

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

I have looked at the Android API and other posts here on stackoverflow, but have not been able to figure this out.

My app downloads files to the sd card. I would like to pop a "loading..." dialog while the file is downloading and then have it disappear when the download is finished. This is what i came up with using the android API:

```
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Loading. Please wait...",true);

//download file

pd.cancel();
```

however the dialog doesn't actually show. when i debug it, it claims that it is showing, but it is obviously not on the screen.

what can i do?

Comment: does the download code run into a separated thread?

Comment: no it runs on the same thread as the activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run the download code into a separated Thread. The easy way is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Look also [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html) on how to use it

Comment: i actually had a meeting where we talked about threading and i figured it out. i also had to put it into a separate activity so my app wouldnt try to load the file before the download activity finished.

thanks for your help! you got the wheels turning.

Answer (score 2):

I have a somewhat similar scenario, more of a level loading pause while stuff is being setup for a phase of a game. I launch the dialog, start level loading in a thread which is passed the context and call this at the end of the thread:

```
mContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        mContext.mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

I find the runOnUiThread() method extremely useful.